# Optimizing AS3 DropShadowFilter

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, optimization

I'm using GreenSock's *TweenMax* to fade in a *TLFTextField* with a *DropShadowFilter* applied. The framerate drops to about **8fps** when I try to do this. Without the shadow, the transition is a consistent 24fps. I know Flash is redrawing the shadow each frame - is there any way I can avoid this?

`cacheAsBitmap` seems to have no noticeable effect. I could draw the textfield to a bitmap, but I'd like that to be a last resort. Is there any override for redrawing the shadow? Or perhaps an alternative method?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: draw just the filter to a bitmapdata and remove all filter from your textfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed the `TextField` to fade in into a parent `Sprite`, cache that sprite as bitmap, and fade the parent in by tweening its alpha. This should make Flash draw the drop shadow only once per entire processing.

```
var fadeholder:Sprite=new Sprite();
fadeholder.addChild(tf); // your textfield
tf.alpha=1;
// it should have filter applied already
fadeholder.cacheAsBitmap=true;
addChild(fadeholder);
```

After you do this, initiate tween on `fadeholder.alpha`, and once it's over, add the textfield to a proper parent ("this", maybe) and remove the obsolete `fadeholder` from display list.